# Extract index values from array in BiQuery data JSON

Tags: arrays, json, google-bigquery

I have imported data from Firestore to BigQuery. The structure of my data is similar to this:

```
data = [
  {
    id: "item1",
    status: {
      options: [
        {
          title: "Approved",
          color: "#00ff00"
        },
        {
          title: "Rejected",
          color: "#ff0000"
        },
        {
          title: "Pending",
          color: "#ffaa00"
        }
      ],
      optionIndex: 0
    }
  },
  {
    id: "item2",
    status: {
      options: [
        {
          title: "Validated",
          color: "#00ff00"
        },
        {
          title: "Invalidated",
          color: "#ff0000"
        }
      ],
      optionIndex: 1
    }
  }
];
```

I successfully run a query to extract the key values such as id:

```
SELECT
  JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.id') AS item_id,
  JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.status.optionIndex') AS option_index
FROM `my_bigquery_table`
```

However, I struggle getting to a solution to select **status.options[status.options.optionIndex]** where I can get title and color of the status into a table. The result I've been aiming for is:

```
id,status_title,status_color
item1,Approved,#00ff00
item2,Invalidated,#ffaa00
```

(I'm doing fine with most basic SQL including joins, but getting the status arrays into a queryable structure where I can select the index hasn't been within my level)

Comment: I'm very confused by the mix of structured data and JSON traversal - what's the schema of your table?

Comment: Ah sorry. The JSON data structure is the 'data' column in the table created by the Firestore importer. I.e. it's how the documents are structured in Firestore and this content structure is copied to the data column in the import table. I'm fairly new to BigQuery but understand this is normal. But it does make the SQL queries quite bad that I have to query into that JSON string. I may be missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION json2array(input STRING)
RETURNS ARRAY<STRING>
LANGUAGE js AS '''
  return JSON.parse(input).map(x=>JSON.stringify(x));
'''; 
SELECT 
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(data, '$.id') AS id,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(option, '$.title') AS status_title,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(option, '$.color') AS status_color
FROM `project.dataset.my_bigquery_table`,
UNNEST([json2array(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.status.options'))[OFFSET(CAST(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(data, '$.status.optionIndex') AS INT64))]]) option
```

If to apply to sample data in your question - output is

```
Row id      status_title    status_color     
1   item1   Approved        #00ff00  
2   item2   Invalidated     #ff0000
```